# WebKit Transitions JQuery AddClass does nothing

Tags: jquery, class, css-transitions

JQuery addclass is not adding a class at all and thus web-kit transitions are not working. In the function below the first add class is working whereas the second is not. What is going on.

Function

```
function closecont() {
    $('#contpanel').addClass('contentclosed');
    $('#slideback').addClass('slideback');
}
```

CSS

```
.gallery .content #slideback {
    position:absolute;
    background:url(images/ui/cont.png) center top;
    height:44px;
    width:24px;
    top:340px;
    left:254px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration:600ms;
}
.slideback {
    opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration:600ms;
}
```

Content closed is working perfectly. .slideback is not. Here is a very similar fiddle that I made.   http://jsfiddle.net/4WmJz/15/

Any ideas .

Marvellous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add the `!important` flags to your styles, but you used it in the first half of your fiddle. That's why it worked with the first element.

By default CSS rules are applied [in a certain order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#cascading-order). More specific selectors override more general ones, so if you add a class (general) to an element, the CSS rule set for the item ID (specific) will take priority.

```
.slideback {
    opacity:1.0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
    -webkit-transition-property:opacity !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration:600ms !important;
}
```

Your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4WmJz/16/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
#reviews #test {
opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition-property:opacity, filter;
-webkit-transition-duration:600ms ,600ms;
 }
```

Do this:

```
 #reviews .hidden{
 opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);
 -webkit-transition-property:opacity, filter;
-webkit-transition-duration:600ms ,600ms;
}
```

Then do this:

```
   <div id="test" class='hidden'>moved</div>
```

Andupdate js to this:

```
$('#moveIt').click(function() {
$('#dropout').addClass('dropopen');
$('#test').removeClass('hidden');
$('#test').addClass('test');
return false;
});
```